# 1999 toyota 4runner wiper wiring question

Tags: electrical, toyota, 4runner

The wiper motor isn't coming on, but shorting to the motor shows it works fine.
I pulled the fuse for the wiper and the fuse for 4x4 right below it.  I don't have a good wiring diagram.

```
---------
| 1 | 2 |   Wiper fuse
---------
| 3 | 4 |   4x4 fuse
---------
```

With the wiper switch on high, reading from battery negative to:  1=~.5v, 2=floating, 3=~12v, 4=~12mv.
Reading from battery positive to: 1=~11.5v, 2=floating 3=~12mv, 4=~12v

I think that indicates to me that the ground side of the lower fuse is #4, while the ground side of the wiper fuse is #1?  And I would think then that I have a break in the circuit somewhere between the battery and #2?  Would the steering column switch account for the .5 v drop?  And then what would that make the .4v from 1 to 4?

I really want to test by just shoving a jumper wire between 3 and 1, but I want a second opinion before I fry something.

Comment: I don't think you'd have a specific ground from the fuse panel. If you pull a fuse, there are two sides. One side is going to be coming from the power source (whether switched or always on), while the other side is going out to the device it is powering. (This may be different for the lights, but not sure.) Each device will be grounded at its location or through a secondary ground wire coming from the device. The fuse box is a pass through for power with the fusible link put in place to kill that power incase of a short.

Comment: That's part of my question.  The simple diagram I have seems to show that the fuse panel is before the switch, so power coming in whether it's one big line powering the entire fuse panel, or one per fuse, and then one "ground" out of the panel to whatever is next in line (which I guess would be multi-function switch [MFS] and then wiper motor and then ground).  I would think that even with the MFS off, I would be able to get +12 from whichever side of the wiper fuse is + to the negative side of the 4x4 switch, but I'm not.

Comment: Was the power turned on via ignition? If this is switched power, you wouldn't see it there with the ignition switch in the off position. Might pick up power from ACC position (wiper might, but I doubt 4x4 would).

Comment: Power was on and the MFS was in high. I even tested the rear wiper to be sure, and it worked (although I can't find the fuse for it at all?)  I also retested the -11.5 I'm getting, and that doesn't change with the switch on or off, so I must be wrong about that being the line to the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the wiper relay output, in addition to any obvious signs of wiring damage. Here's the wiring diagram for the '99 4Runner.[image]

I haven't looked at how it's built myself but if there are no pin numbers and it's drawn as one block - chances are the relay is built in. Check the voltage on the pin 17 of the switch as that's the main power. Then check the voltage at the fuse (take it out, one end should be at 12V when the ignition is at ACC position, against a proven ground point). If there isn't 12V there - run a wire (with a fuse) from the battery to that fuse to see if the wiper motor is operating now. If it does - it's the power to the fuse that's damaged. If it doesn't - have to keep looking, tracing all the points after the fuse.

Comment: By the wiring diagram, the wiper relay is only used for intermittent mode, not the high or low setting.  The diagram will be useful however.

Comment: It's definitely better than I've got, but i'm having a hard time tying it to the physical in my mind (I'm trying my best not to take the dash and fuse panel apart yet).  What is the gray box in the middle?  Just a junction?   What's 3a?  And are the numbers pin numbers?  Is the b-y wire going into the fuse panel one big wire for everything, or just one wire going to those two fuses? (And actually just one fuse in america, right?)

Comment: It looks like for an american 4runner, assuming the central 4-way thing is just a junction, that power will flow through the fuse and into the relay regardless of the position of the wiper switch.  Would this account for me seeing 11.5 volts between 4x4 fuse positive and wiper fuse assumed negative regardless of what position the wiper switch is in?  Maybe grounding through the relay with minimal current or something even when the relay is "off"?

Comment: The small numbers by each connection are the pin numbers on the corresponding connector. I would assume B-Y wire is common power to a lot of stuff in the fuse box. @HandyHowie is correct, looks like the motor is operated by the swich directly if not in intermittent mode, so start by checking the outputs there.

Comment: Yeah, and looks like "Connector 3A at the junction block near the steering column tube under the dash".

Comment: Also, the US version still has the 10A gauge fuse (it is not shown on this particular diagram, but there's a lot more stuff on that fuse). I am not 100% sure, but I think the difference between US and Canadian versions is the lack of the "low windshield fluid" warning float/switch/light in the former variant.

Comment: I was neglecting the washer motor and thinking that US model wouldn't have the interruption between the 3a junction and the relay.  I'm definitely not getting any power at the wiper motor.  As I said, I don't think I'm even getting power at the fuse, and that's one of the things I'm trying to verify; that that's a valid test point.  I'll try to find the relay and see if I have power there, but I did try running the washer and nothing happened (I had a leak while working on the timing belt and didn't bother checking for fluid, but didn't HEAR the motor either, I'll double check).

Comment: If the small number are pin numbers, is the diagram saying that the relay is built into the combination switch, since it doesn't have any pin numbers of its own?

Comment: @user34314, I amended my answer with the procedure I'd use.

Comment: @user34314, what's the voltage between the fuse terminals when the switch is turned on to HIGH?

Comment: Floating like it's disconnected.

Comment: In my original "diagram" 1 and 2 are the wiper fuse.  I'm getting nothing across it, but 11.75 when going from 1 to 3, -12.2 from 3 to 4, and -.4 from 1 to 4.  I've just retested and realized I probably had my polarities reversed for some tests.  I'll update the question with everything referenced to the battery directly.

Comment: I need to stop doing this testing late at night.  I still think my testing indicates that battery positive should be coming in at #2 and that #1 goes through the switch and wiper motor to battery negative.  If it was coming in at #1, I would be getting 12v from #1 to battery negative.  So I think the positive incoming lead is broken, and manually shorting from battery positive to #1 (with a fuse) should send power through and let me turn the wipers on.  Instead it hot-wires the starter, so I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: @user34314, it's hard to say whether 1 or 2 are the positive power there, but if everything were okay you'd get 12V between 1 and 2 and the wiper switch turned on. With the fuse out, you should get a good 12V on either 1 or 2 (that's the power) against proven ground point (not the other fuse). If that's not the case - run a jumper to either terminal of the fuse receiver (with the fuse out) and see if the motor moves.

Comment: Doing electrical troubleshooting at night adds extra spice to it, developing critical thinking of all sorts, as well as polishing the alcohol tolerance. There are definitely benefits to it.

Comment: I've finally worked it out.  I'll add an answer.  1) it's a blown fuse 2) the fuse panel is not wired like what the sticker says it should be wired, but the fuses are arranged like the sticker says they should be.  There's a 20A fuse where the 20A wiper fuse should be, but runs the starter, and there's a 7.5A fuse where the starter is labeled to be, but it's actually the wiper fuse.  I guess 7.5A is good 90% of the time, until my wife tried to run the wipers while they were frozen to the windshield.  I realized the issue when the car wouldn't start with the wiper fuse out.

Comment: @user34314, ah, this sucks you spent so much time on it. Good find though!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this ended up being the issue.  The fuses in the panel are arranged as if the sticker on the door is correct when the door is installed.
[image: lines indicate incorrect reversed fuses. This is NOT how they are supposed to be installed]<sup>**<lines indicate incorrect reversed fuses.  This is NOT how they are supposed to be installed>**</sup>

And it seems to make sense based on number of fuses and is only off by the top left fuse being 20A instead of 30A.  I can't make it out well enough right now, but I'm betting the big "fusible link" or whatever it is is 30A, and that the 20A is either not really active, or is something else, like the fuse I haven't been able to find for the rear wiper.

Regardless, I found out when I tried to start the car with the "wiper" fuse out that the 20A wiper fuse is actually the position for the starter relay.  The 7.5A fuse is in the actual wiper fuse position and was blown.  I guess that explains why the starter kicked in when I shorted the fuse during testing.  (My wife said this all started when she was cleaning the ice off her windshield.  She said she moved it by hand and thought she broke something, but I bet that she had the wipers on; I bet that the 7.5A fuse is enough when the motor is free, but not when the wiper blades are frozen down.)

I verified that the wiper, starter, and stop fuses are all reversed, and I imagine everything else in there is reversed as well.  I swapped the lower four fuses, replaced the blown 7.5, and everything's good to go.  Now I just need to swap all of the others around.

Comment: This is likely a lid from either the Japanese version (Surf) or some other Toyota vehicle alltogether.

Comment: Maybe.  I figure it's more likely that it's just a bad diagram (putting the 30A fusible link in the same grid), the fuses are SUPPOSED to be installed in the same order as the diagram when you're looking at it, and someone just got confused and installed all of the fuses backward at some point in the past.  That doesn't explain that extra 20A, though.  I pulled it out, and it's not the rear wiper.  I didn't check whether it really has any power, though.

Comment: I took a look at the diagram on my '99 4Runner and yes, you appear to be correct. I have exactly the same diagram on my North American 4Runner.